# What is meant by 'linear transformations always map the origin onto itself'?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I've only just started looking at transformations and matrices, but came across this quote in the book I'm learning from. Could someone, in basic terms, help me to understand it?

Comment: Thayt if $\;T:V\to W\;$ is a linear map between linear (vector) spaces $\;V,\,W\;$ )over the same field, of course), then $\;T0_V=0_W\;$ , meaning: $\;T\;$ maps the neutral element wrt to addition in $\;V\;$ to the neutral element wrt addition in $\;W\;$

Answer (score 4):

$$A(0) = A(0+0)= A(0)+A(0)\implies A(0)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Say you have vector spaces $V$ and $W$ and a linear map $T: V \to W$. The statement "linear transforms always map the origin onto itself" means $T(0_V) = 0_W$, where the $0_V$ and $0_W$ are the respective vector addition identities (aka zero vectors). Why must this be true?
$$
T(0_V) = T(0_V + 0_V) = T(0_V) + T(0_V),
$$
where first equality is definition of additive identity in $V$ and second is linearity of $T$. Subtract $T(0_V)$ from each side:
$$
T(0_V) - T(0_V) = T(0_V).
$$
But the LHS is the difference of two identical vectors in $W$, i.e. $0_W = T(0_V)$, which gives the result.